# Trouble with readObject only returning a single array value

Tags: java

I'm taking a course in Java, and the assignment is to write a calendar program that can write and retrieve events from a file.

My problem is that I'm only getting the first value of my written array. returned from the "input.readObject"

Here is my getFile method calling looking to read the file.

```
static String[] Entry = new String [35];

public static void getFile(Object month, String year) throws IOException
{
    ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(month+year+".txt"));
    try
    {
        String[] LoadedEntry = (String[])(input.readObject());
        Entry = (String[]) LoadedEntry;
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("File not found, creating new file...");
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

And the method that calls it, and writes the desired code after the getFile method executes.

```
    public static void saveEvent(String month, int day, String year, String calendarEvent)
{
    String[] EntryF = new String[35];
    String[] Sample = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    try
    {
        getFile(month, year);
        System.out.println("Past getFile");
        EntryF = Entry;
        //EntryF = Sample;
        EntryF[day] = calendarEvent;

        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(month + year+".txt", true));
        output.writeObject(EntryF);
        output.reset();
        output.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Been racking my brain for all day, and cannot get this thing to work... Does anyone see where I went wrong?

I can verify that the object is being saved and passed down into the saveEvent method because the written textfile is changing, but it's just not reading in the full contents of the file correctly..

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: You have no evidence that the object is being written as you expect. So what exactly is `Entry`, and where are you setting it, and what exactly is in it? other than what you're setting here? There is no reason here to believe that it contains anything other than what you're setting here. And why are you messing around with what is evidently a member field inside the `saveEvent()` method at all? NB (1) You don't need the `reset()` call just before the `close()`. NB (2) You can't append to streams written by `ObjectOutputStream:` at least, not without special code, not to be recommended.

Comment: maybe because you are appending to the FileOutputStream?

Comment: Sorry, `Entry` is a static String[] variable used to pass down the `LoadedEntry` information.

Comment: And why are you printing `System.out.println("File not found, creating new file...");` when you don't do any such thing? and when the actual error could be something quite different? When you get an exception print *its* message, not your own. Don't guess in error recovery code. And what exactly is actually happening instead of what you expect? Are you *getting* an exception? If so, what?

Comment: The only exception I get from that block is a "File not found" exception on the first time around, which is why I wrote that.The assigment details were to return a string that there was no file. As it continues back to the saveEvent method which calls it, it creates the file; and doesn't throw that exception again.

Comment: The code you have posted does not behave as you have described. Post the real code, or a correct description of the problem. And it doesn't require a read loop either.

Comment: It behaves exactly as I described - as that was the code that I was running, and was sitting there watching it err exactly as described. The poster of the below answer - that I marked correct - understood the question, and answered with the loop being the solution; which in turn corrected the problem and caused the program to function to expectation. I do appreciate your previous suggestions on making the program run more efficiently though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a loop to read rest of the stream. So far you are reading just the first part of the stream, so the following will have to be in a loop:

> String[] loadedEntry = (String[])(input.readObject());

And you will also need to determine a signal to use to end the loop.
For e.g. using `input.read()` will result in -1 when the end of stream is reached.
You can read the entire file with something like the following:

```
try {
  while (Terminating_Condition) {   
    String[] loadedEntry = (String[]) (input.readObject());
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Man, that was it!!! Took a little tooling, but it led me down the right path. Thanks much, friend!!

Comment: I don't see why a loop is necessary. He's only writing one object to the file. The part about `input.read() != -1` is untested nonsense. It will consume a byte from the input that is supposed to be consumed by `readObject(),` and will cause a `StreamCorruptedException.` The correct looping technique here is to loop until `EOFException` is thrown by `readObject().`

Comment: @EJP could you write up an answer instead of bits and pieces of info here and there. doing that may help us out all.

Comment: @user3320018 I don't have an answer. I don't believe in the existence of the problem as it is stated above. Something is missing, or something is different about the real code. The OP's code should work as is where is, apart from the file append issue which would cause a `StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code AC` when reading the first appended part, which evidently doesn't happen, which is yet another reason not to believe in the code as posted.

Comment: @EJP I am re-read everything. I do not see any direction. we'll need more answers from the OP.

Comment: @EJP we haven't heard any clarification, I am not sure if the question matters. I wonder if this post needs to exist. If you have the power, feel free to delete if you like.

Comment: I've voted to close the question, which is more to the point. That will result in deletion of everything.

Comment: This answer was correct. @EJP The problem, which was stated above; was that it was only saving a single entry of the array. I'm guessing his suggested loop went through the array entries? In any case, his exact snippet (with some editing of the while argument) caused my code to successfully retrieve the entire array and save the required information - which I then passed to a separate function to load array elements and print to a text area. That was the only other portion of code that I didn't include of that class, which was irrelevant to the problem of the code not saving the entire array.

Comment: @Andy  Thank you for clarifying! You have added value to this thread now hence giving +1 to your question.

Comment: @EJP I have adjusted the code to reflect correct the intention. Why the down vote?